# Wireless 802.1x Authentication with WEP Encryption

Tags: wep, 802.1x, peap

I would like to set up Cisco WLC with WLAN with 802.1x authentication. I see that the only encryption mechanism is WEP. Everywhere it says that this algorithm is weak solution? Im I missing something or the combination 802.1x (PEAP) with WEP has some improvements over the basic WEP with PSK ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't improve much. True, 802.1X can provide secure *authentication* if a strong mechanism was chosen (e.g. PEAP or TTLS), and this includes a secure way to derive the encryption keys used for regular network traffic, with each client having its own key.

However, **it doesn't matter how strong the authentication or the key are, when the encryption *algorithm* itself is very weak** – with WEP, the key can be discovered after collecting just a few megabytes of data, and then used to decrypt or even inject traffic. This takes *minutes*.

(Some vendors have a custom protocol called "Dynamic WEP", which changes the key periodically. This is in fact what WPA-TKIP does – it merely sets a new WEP key for every packet. Regular WEP does not support that though.)